# Webpack - Bundle only required CSS files for production

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, webpack-style-loader

I have a Vue app that has 3 different css themes depending on what the 'brand' is set to. Right now it is working in development. I run an npm run dev command and pass in the brand, then set the brand variable to be globally accessible, and then in my main.js file I set the required css dynamically based on what the brand variable is.

```
var brand = window.__BRAND__;

require('../static/' + brand + '/css/typography.css')
require('../static/' + brand + '/css/header.css')
require('../static/' + brand + '/css/main.css')
require('../static/' + brand + '/css/footer.css')


file structure:
static
  foo
    css
  bar
    css
```

So if I run 'npm --brand=bar run dev' it will require '..static/bar/typography.css' etc.

This works great in my local environment; each has it's own distinct look. The issue I'm having now is with building the app for production. Webpack is somehow compiling ALL of the css files into one and I end up with a hybrid app that has some styling from each. Instead, I need it to compile the CSS with ONLY the files that are required. Here is my webpack.prod.conf file:

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

var env = config.build.env

var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        comparisons: false
      },
      sourceMap: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: {
        safe: true
      }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: ['vendor']
    }),
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ]),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

and my config/index.js file:

```
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.
    var path = require('path')

    module.exports = {
      build: {
        env: require('./prod.env'),
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
        assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
        assetsPublicPath: '/',
        productionSourceMap: true,
        // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
        // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
        // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
        // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
        productionGzip: false,
        productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
        // Run the build command with an extra argument to
        // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
        // `npm run build --report`
        // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
        bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
      },
      dev: {
        env: require('./dev.env'),
        port: 8081,
        autoOpenBrowser: true,
        assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
        assetsPublicPath: '/',
        proxyTable: { 
          // proxy all requests starting with /api to jsonplaceholder
          '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:3001',
            changeOrigin: true
            }
        },
        // CSS Sourcemaps off by default because relative paths are "buggy"
        // with this option, according to the CSS-Loader README
        // (https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#sourcemaps)
        // In our experience, they generally work as expected,
        // just be aware of this issue when enabling this option.
        cssSourceMap: false
      }
    }
```

Comment: Not webpack, but have you looked into [purifycss](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss)?